# A UNIX-like way for Windows Paths?

Tags: windows, unix

Is there a way to mimic a UNIX style path when using Windows? I know with mounted network drives, you can do:

```
\\foo-remote\somedirectory\somefile
```

But what about local files? Is there, in some sense, a way to do:

```
\\c\otherdirectory\otherfile
```

With WSL, I can access the Windows partition like this, but I was hoping for something I could use more universally.

Comment: In terms of local UNC and device paths, by default there's "\\localhost\C$", and via mountvol.exe you can get the volume GUID name such as "\\?\Volume{12345678-0000-0000-0000-cba987654321}".

Comment: There's a "Global" link to native "\Device\Global??", e.g. "\\?\Global\C:\Windows", which is useful if a local DOS device is masking the global device.  Or use the "\\?\GlobalRoot" link to the NT root directory, e.g. "\\?\GlobalRoot\Global??\C:\Windows". This can access "local" devices in other logon sessions, if you know the logon session ID under "\Sessions\0\DosDevices\<logon session id>".

Comment: In Windows 10, there's "\\?\BootPartition", which is usually the C: drive. Windows 10 also has enumerated-volume and partition names such as "\\?\Harddisk0Partition2" and "\\?\HarddiskVolume2". These are based on the native NT names such as "\Device\HarddiskVolume2" and "\Device\Harddisk0\Partition2".

Comment: Try /c/otherdirectory/otherfile

Comment: There is no VFS root directory in Windows to support a path like "/c". Instead, there's a root directory in the object namespace (directly available in the NT API). Device objects are created in "\Device". For example, the boot volume device might be "\Device\HarddiskVolume2". This is a viable path for the device, e.g. "\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32", which would be like using "/dev/sda1/bin" in Unix, if that were possible.

Comment: The names in "\Device" are typically auto-enumerated names, so symbolic links to devices are usually used instead. These are created either in "\Global??" or in a per-logon directory "\Sessions\0\DosDevices\<logon session id>". These two object directories are merged by a special "\??\" virtual directory, for which the system first searches a user's local device links and then the global device links.

Comment: The Windows file API always translates paths to use "\??\", e.g. "C:" becomes "\??\C:" and "\\server\share" becomes "\??\UNC\server\share". A Windows program can use this directly via the local-device prefix "\\?\", which bypasses all Windows path processing (i.e. quirky DOS rules) except to replace "\\?\" with the native NT "\??\" prefix.

Comment: @eryksun Is there anyway to avoid the colon?

Comment: I listed several alternatives that don't use a colon.